# Use of Camera app and firebase to store value Error in onSuccess class

Tags: android

hy every one in am new to the android studio and trying to make a project which use gallary or camera images to store in firebase tried alot method but cant get a best one if any one could help me out 
In this there is a error in OnSuccess " `Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();`" here `getDownloadUrl` is not resolved.
ans in same class there is a error  "   `startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));` "

i dnt know what this code are used for soo pls help me out

```
private void startPosting() {

        mProgress.setMessage("Posting to blog...");


        final String title_val = mPostTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        final String desc_val = mPostDesc.getText().toString().trim();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && mImageUri != null) {

            mProgress.show();
            StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Blog_Images").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

            filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
                    newPost.child("title").setValue(title_val);
                    newPost.child("desc").setValue(desc_val);
                    newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());


                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `getDownloadUrl()` is deprecated.

With the small amount of information provided, I'm not sure what exactly you are asking, but you can try this.

```
 filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() { 
    @Override 
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) { 

        Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getResult();
        String downloadURL = downloadUri.toString(); 

        DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();    
        newPost.child("title").setValue(title_val);
        newPost.child("desc").setValue(desc_val);
        newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadURL);

        mProgress.dismiss();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));             

    } 
});
```

Comment: Here is the full code sir i need a app to run camera and store image in imageview and then save it to the firebase online.

Comment: Can uh provide me a source code of app in which we can access camera click image show in imageview and upload it to fire base and reterive it back i know how to successfull get connected to firebase but m not able to get codes pls help me out

Comment: Sorry but StackOverflow if not a "share me your code" or "create me an app" service. It is to help each other resolve specific issues. You are basically asking me to create your app for you.

Comment: okie but atlst help me out easy way to create it on my own?? and refferences?